# Google Maps JS API v3- Marker Clusterer/ Marker Icon/ Info windows

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, api, google-maps-api-3

Before i begin let me explain that i am a newbie to Javascript and Google Maps API, and so what i am about to ask may be very simple to you knowledgeable, experienced script writers out there!
Basically i have begun writing a script to show multiple markers on a map of the UK. I think i have discovered a way of doing this (current script to follow), however i would also like to add the marker clusterer function (so that points within a certain distance cluster together), in addition to changing the marker icon to an image i have saved on file. 
Finally as well as just adding the points i would also like to add an Info Window to every marker. This window needs to be able to display an image and text.

If there is anyone out there who can help and maybe tweak my script to include everything listed above i would really appreciate it!

This script will also be scaled up eventually to include over 1000 markers, so if anyone can help and they could also perhaps add a note as to where i would include the image file for the icon/ where the new info window script would go (as i add to each marker) then it would be super!

This is the script as i currently have it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['1', 53.682401, -1.498260, 4],
  ['2', 53.681844, -1.496072, 5],
  ['4', 53.690408, -1.628518, 2],
  ['5', 53.713762, -1.632297, 1],
  ['6', 50.466238, -3.528505, 1],
  ['7', 50.435496, -3.566492, 1],
  ['8', 50.546012, -3.496630, 1],
  ['9', 50.529788, -3.611082, 1],
  ['10', 50.620188, -3.411804, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.664097, -2.752708),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
//array to store the markers - to cluster them
var markers = [];
// i have added an image to each marker
var locations = [
  ['1', 53.682401, -1.498260, 4, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['2', 53.681844, -1.496072, 5, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['4', 53.690408, -1.628518, 2, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['5', 53.713762, -1.632297, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['6', 50.466238, -3.528505, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['7', 50.435496, -3.566492, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['8', 50.546012, -3.496630, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['9', 50.529788, -3.611082, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['10', 50.620188, -3.411804, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png']
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.664097, -2.752708),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
   icon: locations[i][4]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent('marker number: ' +locations[i][0] +'<br/><IMG SRC=" '+locations[i][4] +'">');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

// add marker to array
 markers.push(marker);   
 }
// create cluster
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/pfa4w0w5/

docs:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=de#simple_icons

Comment: Wow bnz that is brilliant thank you! Although would it be possible for you to explain how I could create an info window for each marker so that rather than saying 'marker number x' I can put my own editable text in there and perhaps even an image?

I have inputted some text where I think it would go (after the 1,2,3 etc of this part of the script:

    var locations = [
    ['1', 53.682401, -1.498260, 4, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],

however it just says 'marker number: (inputted text)' on the info window.

Comment: welcome - code was updated, now everytime you click on the marker, a new infowindow will be created with data from your locations array. i used the marker number as well as image to display in the infowindow, meaning position [0] AND [4].

Answer (score 0):

Wow bnz that is brilliant thank you! Although would it be possible for you to explain how I could create an info window for each marker so that rather than saying 'marker number x' I can put my own editable text in there and perhaps even an image?

I have inputted some text where I think it would go (after the 1,2,3 etc of this part of the script:

```
var locations = [
['1', 53.682401, -1.498260, 4, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
```

however it just says 'marker number: (inputted text)' on the info window.

Thanks again once for your help you are helped me massively!